# Rollup replace plugin with typescript can't find variable name

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, rollup, dotenv

I am using `@rollup/plugin-replace` to use `dotenv` in `Svelte`.

When I replace the variables like below,

```
replace({
  preventAssignment: true,
  DATABASE_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.SUPABASE_URL),
})
```

and use above in `main.ts`, it can't find the variable but prints well in the console.

[image]

The `DATABASE_URL` actaully exists. It is just a typescript error.
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

[replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-replace) is going to do a literal string find-and-replace, so if you define your configuration like:

```
replace({
  preventAssignment: true,
  DATABASE_URL: process.env.SUPABASE_URL,
})
```

you should then treat `DATABASE_URL` in your code as a value (i.e., not like a variable). So:

```
const url = "DATABASE_URL";
connect(url, ...);
```